# Spring MVC Ajax Request to Refresh Dynamic Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I currently have a spring mvc app that gets a list of users from a database and displays their information in a table using JSP to basically loop through each object in the list and create a table row for them.

Each user has an expiry date attribute as part of their record in the database. What I want to achieve is basically a button that when toggled shows or hides all users that have expired (i.e. their expiry date is less than today's date).

For this I am trying to use AJAX calls to my controller to fetch me all users expired or not OR only users that haven't expired depending on how the button is toggled.

What I would like help on is the best way to achieve this as I can think of a few nasty ways of doing it like having a separate page and refreshing but I am confused on a few things.

Should I just ditch the JSP looping through to make the table and make a method in JavaScript that creates that table when given the data? If so how do I get the data from the controller to JavaScript, can an AJAX call to a controller return me a list of my user objects?

My best guess is that instead of adding a list of objects to a model and letting JSP do the work, that I instead return a JSON with the data and use JavaScript to build the table. I can then call an update method to re-build the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. You have 2 options:

1. Have AJAX call return html (i.e. jsp) for the table and then replace
   the body of the table
2. Use JavaScript to build the table and then
   update the table with AJAX call which returns JSON.

If you want to get more sophisticated, you could use a JavaScript framework like `Knockout.js` which would let you mark up the table and refresh the table without too much of JavaScript writing.

Comment: Thanks for this - I ended up using number 2 which works perfectly (except some formatting of the tables but that's a JS issue!)

Answer (score -2):

Blurgh I'm not sure why this question has received so much attention, especially now in the days of angular but if you are struggling with this then I would strongly recommend the following library:

https://www.ag-grid.com/